# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when using % wildcard from Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select, syntax-error

The query I am facing trouble with was working fine until I used `%` wildcard in `LIKE` clause. :-

This was fine (printed from Java):-

```
select acc.*, service.* 
    from com_accounts acc 
    left join com_subscriptions service on acc.cust_id = service.cust_id
    where 1=1 and  UPPER(acc.first_name) LIKE UPPER(?)
```

This threw an error (printed from Java code):-

```
select acc.*, service.* 
    from com_accounts acc 
    left join com_subscriptions service on acc.cust_id = service.cust_id 
    where 1=1 and  UPPER(acc.first_name) LIKE UPPER('%'?'%')
```

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Why are you using `where 1=1`?

Comment: Its a dynamic query, with multiple optional clause

Comment: @notyou simple trick to allow the add of condition dynamicaly without the need to check if you need to add a `where` or an `and`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this query, you'd just have three consecutive strings with no operator between them, which is, as you've seen, not a legal syntax in Oracle. Concatenating them using the `||` operator should solve the issue:

```sql
select acc.*, service.* 
from com_accounts acc 
left join com_subscriptions service on acc.cust_id = service.cust_id 
where 1=1 and  UPPER(acc.first_name) LIKE UPPER('%' || ? || '%')
-- Here --------------------------------------------^----^
```

Answer (score 1):

Mayber using `CONCAT` function you can solve your answer.

```
select acc.*, service.* 
    from com_accounts acc 
    left join com_subscriptions service on acc.cust_id = service.cust_id 
    where 1=1 and  UPPER(acc.first_name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%',?,'%'))
```

Comment: `concat()` only allows two parameters in Oracle